# Can't boot server after attempting to upgrade 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: boot

I have a Rackspace Cloud Server (that was) running 12.04 LTS. The other day, after logging in and doing some routine maintenance, I noticed the server telling me that 14.04 LTS was available, and to install it, all I had to do was run 'do-release-upgrade'. That sounds easy! So, being tired, and not really on top of my game, I decided to give it a whirl. I don't want to be left behind, after all.

Well, oops. That probably wasn't such a good idea after all. After the upgrade, the last step is of course, to reboot. The server would not reboot. I went into Rescue Mode (a Rackspace service that allows you to mount the filesystem using another OS) - so I can get access to the server's file system. I think that I need to either edit my `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file or my `/etc/fstab` file, or both? Or should I be sniffing around some completely other area?

I don't have a lot of experience working with boot loaders and such, so I am hoping someone is willing to help out with any tips or advice.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem. Rackspace said that their images simply "don't support" an upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04, and recommended creating a new cloud server using 14.04 and transferring everything. A disappointing answer for sure.